# Number of $3 \times 3$ matrices with integer entries such that $AA^t$ is the identity matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthogonal-matrices

Let $S$ be the set of all $3 \times 3$ matrices $A$ with integer entries such that the product $AA^t$ is the identity matrix.

Then $|S|$ is :

1. 23.
2. 24
3. 48
4. 60

Answer is $48$ but I don't know how to solve it.